# Changing the video background of this elementor slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, elementor

I'm working on [this Wordpress website](https://www.askdrdougnow.com) and trying to change the video background of the slider on the homepage. I see it in the code, I see it in the site editor, and it seems to be part of a revolution slider, yet in this slider's properties, I cannot find any instruction relating to it.

Has anyone worked with this situation before? Did I miss something obvious? or did I just research the wrong question?

Here is the JSON definition of the slider in question:

```
{
    "addOns": [],
    "carousel": {
        "borderRadius": 0,
        "borderRadiusUnit": "px",
        "ease": "power3.inOut",
        "fadeOut": true,
        "horizontal": "center",
        "infinity": false,
        "justify": false,
        "justifyMaxWidth": false,
        "maxItems": 3,
        "maxOpacity": 100,
        "maxRotation": 0,
        "offsetScale": false,
        "paddingBottom": 0,
        "paddingTop": 0,
        "rotation": false,
        "scale": false,
        "scaleDown": 50,
        "showAllLayers": "false",
        "snap": true,
        "space": 0,
        "speed": 800,
        "stretch": false,
        "varyFade": false,
        "varyRotate": false,
        "varyScale": false,
        "vertical": "center"
    },
    "class": "",
    "codes": {
        "css": "",
        "javascript": ""
    },
    "def": {
        "autoResponsive": true,
        "background": {
            "fit": "cover",
            "fitX": 100,
            "fitY": 100,
            "imageSourceType": "full",
            "position": "center center",
            "positionX": 0,
            "positionY": 0,
            "repeat": "no-repeat"
        },
        "delay": 9000,
        "intelligentInherit": true,
        "panZoom": {
            "blurEnd": 0,
            "blurStart": 0,
            "duration": 10000,
            "ease": "none",
            "fitEnd": 100,
            "fitStart": 100,
            "rotateEnd": 0,
            "rotateStart": 0,
            "set": false,
            "xEnd": 0,
            "xStart": 0,
            "yEnd": 0,
            "yStart": 0
        },
        "responsiveChilds": true,
        "responsiveOffset": true,
        "transition": "fade",
        "transitionDuration": 300
    },
    "general": {
        "autoPlayVideoOnMobile": true,
        "disableFocusListener": false,
        "disableOnMobile": false,
        "disablePanZoomMobile": false,
        "firstSlide": {
            "alternativeFirstSlide": 1,
            "alternativeFirstSlideSet": false,
            "duration": 300,
            "set": false,
            "slotAmount": 7,
            "type": "fade"
        },
        "layerSelection": false,
        "lazyLoad": "none",
        "nextSlideOnFocus": false,
        "progressbar": {
            "color": "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
            "height": 5,
            "position": "bottom",
            "set": false
        },
        "slideshow": {
            "initDelay": 0,
            "loopSingle": false,
            "presetSliderHeight": false,
            "shuffle": false,
            "slideShow": true,
            "stopAfterLoops": 0,
            "stopAtSlide": 1,
            "stopOnHover": false,
            "stopSlider": false,
            "viewPort": false,
            "viewPortArea": {
                "d": {
                    "e": false,
                    "u": "",
                    "v": "200px"
                },
                "m": {
                    "e": false,
                    "u": "",
                    "v": "200px"
                },
                "n": {
                    "e": false,
                    "u": "",
                    "v": "200px"
                },
                "t": {
                    "e": false,
                    "u": "",
                    "v": "200px"
                }
            },
            "viewPortStart": "wait",
            "waitForInit": false
        },
        "useWPML": false
    },
    "googleFont": [],
    "hero": {
        "activeSlide": -1
    },
    "id": "",
    "layout": {
        "bg": {
            "color": "transparent",
            "dottedOverlay": "none",
            "fit": "cover",
            "image": "",
            "imageSourceType": "full",
            "padding": 0,
            "position": "center center",
            "repeat": "no-repeat",
            "shadow": 0,
            "useImage": false
        },
        "position": {
            "addClear": false,
            "align": "center",
            "fixedOnTop": false,
            "marginBottom": 0,
            "marginLeft": 0,
            "marginRight": 0,
            "marginTop": 0
        },
        "spinner": {
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "type": "0"
        }
    },
    "layouttype": "fullwidth",
    "modal": {
        "bodyclass": "",
        "cover": true,
        "coverColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        "horizontal": "center",
        "vertical": "middle"
    },
    "modalshortcode": "[rev_slider usage=\"modal\" alias=\"slider-1\"][/rev_slider]",
    "nav": {
        "arrows": {
            "alwaysOn": true,
            "animDelay": "1000ms",
            "animSpeed": "1000ms",
            "hideDelay": 200,
            "hideDelayMobile": 1200,
            "hideOver": false,
            "hideOverLimit": 0,
            "hideUnder": false,
            "hideUnderLimit": 778,
            "left": {
                "align": "slider",
                "anim": "fade",
                "horizontal": "left",
                "offsetX": 30,
                "offsetY": 0,
                "vertical": "center"
            },
            "preset": "default",
            "presets": [],
            "right": {
                "align": "slider",
                "anim": "fade",
                "horizontal": "right",
                "offsetX": 30,
                "offsetY": 0,
                "vertical": "center"
            },
            "rtl": false,
            "set": false,
            "style": "1000"
        },
        "bullets": {
            "align": "slider",
            "alwaysOn": true,
            "anim": "fade",
            "animDelay": "1000ms",
            "animSpeed": "1000ms",
            "direction": "horizontal",
            "hideDelay": 200,
            "hideDelayMobile": 1200,
            "hideOver": false,
            "hideOverLimit": 0,
            "hideUnder": false,
            "hideUnderLimit": 778,
            "horizontal": "center",
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 20,
            "preset": "default",
            "presets": [],
            "rtl": false,
            "set": false,
            "space": 5,
            "style": "3000",
            "vertical": "bottom"
        },
        "keyboard": {
            "direction": "horizontal",
            "set": false
        },
        "mouse": {
            "reverse": "default",
            "set": "off"
        },
        "preview": {
            "height": 100,
            "width": 50
        },
        "swipe": {
            "blockDragVertical": false,
            "direction": "horizontal",
            "minTouch": 1,
            "set": false,
            "setDesktopCarousel": true,
            "setMobileCarousel": true,
            "setOnDesktop": false,
            "velocity": 75
        },
        "tabs": {
            "align": "slider",
            "alwaysOn": true,
            "amount": 5,
            "anim": "fade",
            "animDelay": "1000ms",
            "animSpeed": "1000ms",
            "direction": "horizontal",
            "height": 50,
            "hideDelay": 200,
            "hideDelayMobile": 1200,
            "hideOver": false,
            "hideOverLimit": 0,
            "hideUnder": false,
            "hideUnderLimit": 778,
            "horizontal": "center",
            "innerOuter": "inner",
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 20,
            "padding": 5,
            "preset": "default",
            "presets": [],
            "rtl": false,
            "set": false,
            "space": 5,
            "spanWrapper": false,
            "style": "4000",
            "vertical": "bottom",
            "width": 100,
            "widthMin": 100,
            "wrapperColor": "transparent"
        },
        "thumbs": {
            "align": "slider",
            "alwaysOn": true,
            "amount": 5,
            "anim": "fade",
            "animDelay": "1000ms",
            "animSpeed": "1000ms",
            "direction": "horizontal",
            "height": 50,
            "hideDelay": 200,
            "hideDelayMobile": 1200,
            "hideOver": false,
            "hideOverLimit": 0,
            "hideUnder": false,
            "hideUnderLimit": 778,
            "horizontal": "center",
            "innerOuter": "inner",
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 20,
            "padding": 5,
            "preset": "default",
            "presets": [],
            "rtl": false,
            "set": false,
            "space": 5,
            "spanWrapper": false,
            "style": "2000",
            "vertical": "bottom",
            "width": 100,
            "widthMin": 100,
            "wrapperColor": "transparent"
        }
    },
    "parallax": {
        "ddd": {
            "BGFreeze": false,
            "layerOverflow": false,
            "overflow": false,
            "shadow": false,
            "zCorrection": 65
        },
        "disableOnMobile": false,
        "levels": [
            5,
            10,
            15,
            20,
            25,
            30,
            35,
            40,
            45,
            46,
            47,
            48,
            49,
            50,
            51,
            30
        ],
        "mouse": {
            "bgSpeed": 0,
            "layersSpeed": 0,
            "origo": "slidercenter",
            "speed": 0,
            "type": "scroll"
        },
        "set": false,
        "setDDD": false
    },
    "scrolleffects": {
        "bg": false,
        "direction": "both",
        "disableOnMobile": false,
        "layers": false,
        "maxBlur": 10,
        "multiplicator": "1.3",
        "multiplicatorLayers": "1.3",
        "parallaxLayers": false,
        "set": false,
        "setBlur": false,
        "setFade": false,
        "setGrayScale": false,
        "staticLayers": false,
        "staticParallaxLayers": false,
        "tilt": 30
    },
    "scrolltimeline": {
        "ease": "none",
        "fixed": false,
        "fixedEnd": 4000,
        "fixedStart": 2000,
        "layers": false,
        "set": false,
        "speed": 500
    },
    "shortcode": "[rev_slider alias=\"slider-1\"][/rev_slider]",
    "size": {
        "custom": {
            "d": true,
            "m": true,
            "n": true,
            "t": true
        },
        "disableForceFullWidth": false,
        "editorCache": {
            "d": 500,
            "m": 270,
            "n": 600,
            "t": 430
        },
        "forceOverflow": false,
        "fullScreenOffset": "",
        "fullScreenOffsetContainer": "",
        "gridEQModule": false,
        "height": {
            "d": "500px",
            "m": "270px",
            "n": "600px",
            "t": "430px"
        },
        "keepBPHeight": false,
        "maxHeight": 0,
        "maxWidth": 0,
        "minHeight": "",
        "minHeightFullScreen": "",
        "overflow": false,
        "overflowHidden": false,
        "respectAspectRatio": false,
        "useFullScreenHeight": true,
        "width": {
            "d": 1240,
            "m": 480,
            "n": 1024,
            "t": 778
        }
    },
    "skins": {
        "cid": 2,
        "colors": [
            {
                "alias": "Highlight",
                "ref": [],
                "v": "#ff0000"
            },
            {
                "alias": "Headline Text",
                "ref": [],
                "v": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "alias": "Content Text",
                "ref": [],
                "v": "#00ffff"
            }
        ],
        "colorsAtStart": false
    },
    "snap": {
        "adjust": "none",
        "gap": 20,
        "helpLines": false,
        "snap": false
    },
    "source": {
        "facebook": {
            "album": "",
            "appId": "",
            "appSecret": "",
            "count": "",
            "pageURL": "",
            "transient": 1200,
            "typeSource": "album"
        },
        "flickr": {
            "apiKey": "",
            "count": "",
            "galleryURL": "",
            "groupURL": "",
            "photoSet": "",
            "transient": 1200,
            "type": "publicphotos",
            "userURL": ""
        },
        "gallery": [],
        "instagram": {
            "count": "",
            "hashTag": "",
            "transient": 1200,
            "type": "user",
            "userId": ""
        },
        "post": {
            "category": "",
            "excerptLimit": 55,
            "fetchType": "cat_tag",
            "list": "",
            "maxPosts": 30,
            "sortBy": "ID",
            "sortDirection": "DESC",
            "subType": "post",
            "types": "post"
        },
        "twitter": {
            "accessSecret": "",
            "accessToken": "",
            "consumerKey": "",
            "consumerSecret": "",
            "count": "",
            "excludeReplies": false,
            "imageOnly": false,
            "includeRetweets": false,
            "transient": 1200,
            "userId": ""
        },
        "vimeo": {
            "albumId": "",
            "channelName": "",
            "count": "",
            "groupName": "",
            "transient": 1200,
            "typeSource": "user",
            "userName": ""
        },
        "woo": {
            "category": "",
            "excerptLimit": 55,
            "featuredOnly": false,
            "inStockOnly": false,
            "maxProducts": 30,
            "regPriceFrom": "",
            "regPriceTo": "",
            "salePriceFrom": "",
            "salePriceTo": "",
            "sortBy": "ID",
            "sortDirection": "DESC",
            "types": "product"
        },
        "youtube": {
            "api": "",
            "channelId": "",
            "count": "",
            "playList": "",
            "transient": 1200,
            "typeSource": "channel"
        }
    },
    "sourcetype": "gallery",
    "troubleshooting": {
        "alternateImageType": "off",
        "alternateURL": "",
        "ignoreHeightChanges": false,
        "ignoreHeightChangesUnderLimit": 0,
        "jsInBody": false,
        "jsNoConflict": false,
        "outPutFilter": "none",
        "simplify_ie8_ios4": false
    },
    "type": "standard",
    "version": "6.2.2",
    "visibility": {
        "hideAllLayersUnderLimit": 0,
        "hideSelectedLayersUnderLimit": 0,
        "hideSliderUnderLimit": 0
    },
    "wrapperclass": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that is is revolution slider. This is the source  I saw for the video

```
<source src="//askdrdougnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/videoplayback.webm" type="video/mp4" data-stylerecorder="true" style="text-align: left; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-style: none; margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;">
```

I know Revolution Slider has a place for editing all sliders and you can set the background of a slider as a video so that is were you would need to find and remove it.